# What's the best way of generating the Authorizing access to a REST API?

Tags: java, firebase, rest, authentication, jwt

I have an application which works with REST APIs. Below is the structure.

1. Email and Password credential are stored in Firebase. So Authentication happens at the firebase end.
2. Back end is a REST API. I am using JWT Token for authorizing access to the REST API.
3. Email and Salted Hashed Password also stored in the local database. (In below, you will see why)

Now, to request a JWT token, I have a method called `authenticate(email, password)`. I pass my Email and Password as params. This will cross check my credentials with the local database and release me a JWT Token. When the REST API is used in the app, this `authenticate(email, password)` method is called only after authenticating the user with the firebase.

Now, we have a problem. I have destroyed the concept of firebase by having the credentials in local database. I can't even use the easy ***password request*** features offered by firebase because I have a local copy of credentials which need to be updated too.

The only reason for me to store the credentials in local database is this generating Authorization Access to the REST API. I could have used `authenticate(email)` easily without the password, but I thought then anyone who has the email would gain easy access by using a tool such as `postman`. Because you just pass your email and you have the JWT token, then you are good to go.

But my approach of storing a copy of password in local database is now a mess. Whats the best way to generate the Authorization (JWT Token) to a user? Just using `authenticate(email)` good enough?

**Update**

I am using Amazon Services. So I am open to such options, such as blocking access except the App etc, if anything like that is possible.